# Method to adding an OR after a THEN in a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to verify if data in one column equals another, and using CASE statements to do them, I was wondering if there's a way to specify that a value can equal the value itself, or NA.

An example of the table:

```
Column 1  |  Column 2
A0            A0
A0            NA
B1            B1
B1            NA
C2            C2
C2            NA
```

The code that I have is

```
select c1, c2, case when c1 = 'A0' then 'A0'  
                    when c1 = 'B1' then 'B1'
                    when c1 = 'C2' then 'C2' end
from dbo
where case when c1 = 'A0' then 'A0'  
                    when c1 = 'B1' then 'B1'
                    when c1 = 'C2' then 'C2' end != c2
```

This would tell me where there are rows where c1 doesn't equal c2, but the rows that I fetch are all NA. Is it possible to account for c1 to equal either c2, or NA? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: BTW, that's a `case` _expression_. (Since it returns a value.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I made an edit to the code; I want to verify that the only two values that a record in c1 could take is the value itself or NA. For example, a1 can equal a1 or NA. The code will pull nothing if every record in c1 = c2, but the records I'm currently pulling are where c2 = NA. I want to account for the possibility of c1 equaling NA. In theory, I'd like to be able to say THEN 'A0' or 'NA' in the case statements, but that won't work.

Comment: What is your expected output for this sample data?

Comment: I expect it to pull nothing because I'm saying I want instances where the case statement doesn't equal c2, meaning I've accounted for all possibilities. But what I'm pulling right now is instances where c2 equals NA.

Comment: Then why doesn't D Stanley's answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you're looking for, but I think you want:

```
where (c1 != c2 AND c2 != 'NA')
```

or

```
where not (c1 = c2 OR c2 = 'NA')
```

whichever makes the most logical sense to you.

I also don't see what the `case` statement does for you - right now it is just repeating the value of `c1`.

Comment: The case expression returns NULL for other values. (Probably not meant to...)

Answer (score 1):

No need for case statements.

Full outer join between the two will match the two columns and also return records where only one of the columns has values and the other one is null. If you want to return only cases where the two match OR C2 is null, then use left join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.col1, case when seq = 1 then t.col2 else 'NA' end as col2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by ?) as seq
      from table t
     ) t;
```

`?` indicates ordering columns.